# Version of scipy is not recognized in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ffbe1855cb9e> in <module>
----> 1 scipy._version_

AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '_version_'
```

The above message keeps on popping up if I try to find the version of scipy in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Can we see the command lines you are using?

Comment: That should probably have been `scipy.__version__` with two underscores each.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using just one underscore, use it twice

`scipy.__version__`

Should work.

Comment: Try to run the `pip show scipy` at your prompt. Pay attention and don't execute inside a python environment.